# while loop to calculate the maximum of two numbers

Tags: python

i just started learning python; i am totally new to programming. kindly look at this post and tell me if my variable declaration at the outset is wrong, and what better way(s) i can write the code. maximum of two numbers using the if else statement. python. thanks.

```
#determine the maximum of two numbers
A = 2
B=1
print 'Exit program by entering 0 for the first integer.'
while A != B:
    A = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    if A == 0:
        break
    B = int(input('Enter a second integer: '))    
    if A > B:
        print 'The maximum number is {0}'.format(A)
    if B > A:
        print 'The maximum number is ' + str(B)

print('Done')
```

Can u help me fix it into a loop? @maze88 and other gurus pls.

```
while True:
    try:
        A=int(input('Enter a number:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer! Try again.')
    else:
        break

while True:
    try:
        B=int(input('Enter a second number:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer! Try again.')
    else:
        break


if A>B:
    print(A)
elif B>A:
    print(B)
else:
    print('Equal numbers')

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code Python 2? If it is, I recommend using Python 3.5.2 instead as it is newer and not many people use Python 2 anymore.

But anyway, the first improvement you could make is using the elif statements, instead of just using 3 if statements. You could also make the formatting a little better to make it easier to read for other programmers.

Like this:

```
#determine the maximum of two numbers
A = 2
B = 1

print 'Exit program by entering 0 for the first integer.'

while A != B:
    A = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    B = int(input('Enter a second integer: '))

    if A == 0:
        break    

    elif A > B:
        print 'The maximum number is {0}'.format(A)

    elif B > A:
        print 'The maximum number is ' + str(B)


print 'Done'
```

Elif statements would be better for this case because in the second if statement

```
if A > B:
```

If A is bigger than B, the next 2 elif statements would be ignored, but in your code, Python checks the if statements even if A is bigger than B.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right. But I would use `max()` function.

```
print 'The maximum number is ' + str(max(A,B))
```

Comment: thanks. i just want to get the hang of the conditional statements before using the inbuilt functions. thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fine and works, you seem to have grasped the basic usage of conditional statements.
Here is your code with a few basic changes I made, go over them and hopefully you will learn something new.

```
A = 2
B = 1
print 'Exit program by entering 0 for the first integer.'

while A != B:
    A = input('Enter an integer: ')  # change 1
    if not A:  # change 2
        break
    B = input('Enter a second integer: ')  # change 1

    if A > B:
        print 'The maximum number is {0}'.format(A)

    elif A < B:  # change 3
        print 'The maximum number is ', B   # change 4

    else:  # change 5
        print 'The numbers are equal'
        break

print 'Done'
```

#### Changes:

1. The `input()` function does not need the `int()` function you had around it. this would only be needed if you were using `raw_input()`.
2. Any *non-zero* integer will always evaluate as *True*, we can use this rule in combination with the `not` *keyword*, therefore causing the condition to evaluate as *True* only if `A` is equal to `0`.
3. Instead of using multiple `if` statements, especially if they are nested, you can use `elif` to test additional conditions - assuming your previous `if` (and previous additional `elif`s, if existent) was not evaluated as *True*.
4. Another alternative way to format a string; although the preferred method is as you did with `A`.
5. Added an `else` branch to deal with all other cases (where none of the `if` or `elif` conditions were met), in this case it would mean that `A` and `B` are equal, so I also added a print statement to say so.

**Expansion idea:** Make your program check that the user input is the correct *type* of data (*integer*, in your case) or return a message stating if otherwise.

Comment: pls check my update on the code. I cant seem to put it in a loop, and still use the try...except function. Any other guru out there who can help, kindly jump in.